# SUM of 2 columns from VLOOKUP in Google Sheets when the search key is not in both columns

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have 2 columns of File # data, representing different weeks in a payroll cycle. I also have 2 columns of Regular Hours data. I am using VLOOKUP and SUM to add the Regular Hours together to receive hours for the pay period.

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP($AI2,RICS_TimeClocks!O$2:S,4, FALSE) , VLOOKUP($AI2,RICS_TimeClocks!T$2:X,4, FALSE))
```

I have the File #s and Names flattened into one column each with

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(
```

The issue I have now though, is that there are employees that only worked on one of the weeks, resulting in a

> "Did not find value '____' in VLOOKUP evaluation"...

Any suggestions so that the formula can function when there is information in only one of 2 data columns? Example, File # 43021 only works in the second week, and File # 43034 only works in the first week, but I still want to be able to compute and display their total hours.

...or a better way to match and add the information into another flattened column of information?

[image: ScreenShot of Google Sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try IFNA set to zero:

```
=SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP($AI2, RICS_TimeClocks!O$2:S, 4, 0), 0), 
     IFNA(VLOOKUP($AI2, RICS_TimeClocks!T$2:X, 4, 0), 0))
```